# Vertical space between headlines, tables, images and the following text too large

Tags: spacing, floats

Is there a way to **globally** set a value (or minimum and maximum value) for the vertical space between, for instance,

headlines, tables, images and the like

**and**

the following text.

Right now I have the problem with my document that some of these vertical spaces are just too big and it does not look very pretty.

Comment: Try to influence the length `\floatsep`. What do you mean with `headline`? Maybe captions?

Comment: Without more information about your document it is hard to tell what is causing this behaviour. I typically forget to remove the last `\\ ` in a math environment, this introduces extra vertical space after the environment and naturally cannot be dealt with globally. Or if you use the `center` environment in figures instead of `\centering` you introduce extra vertical space.

Comment: [`savetrees`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savetrees) gets rid of a lot of vertical space.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you probably use a document class that stretches variable spaces to make the text always fit the complete page. This can in some cases cause the problem you described. Add a [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) to your question or at least tell us your document class.

Answer (score 4):

This broad answer is perhaps sufficient for a vague question.

Here is a summary of the parameters (lengths/dimensions and control sequences) that affect float placement or layout, as given by the [`layouts` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) (p 21 onward) and some extracts from the [`source2e` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.tex):

Where floats may appear on a page and how many appear there are specified by the following float placement parameters. The numbers are named like counters so the user can set them with the ordinary counter-setting commands:

- `\topnumber`: Number of floats allowed at the `t`op of a page (default is `2`);
- `\bottomnumber`: Number of floats allowed at the `b`ottom of a page (default is `1`);
- `\totalnumber`: The total number of floats allowed per page; this includes in-text floats (default is `3`);
- `\topfraction`: The fraction of `\textheight` `t`op floats may occupy on a page (default is `0.7`);
- `\bottomfraction`: The fraction of `\textheight` `b`ottom floats may occupy on a page (default is `0.3`); and
- `\textfraction`: The minimum fraction of a page that must contain text (default is `0.2`).

[image]

Other page style parameters:

- `\floatsep`: Space left between floats (default is `12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt`);
- `\textfloatsep`: Space between last top float or first bottom float and the text (default is `20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt`);
- `\topfigrule`: Command to place rule (or whatever) between floats at top of page and text. Executed in inner vertical mode right before the `\textfloatsep` skip separating the 
  oats from the text. Must occupy zero vertical space;
- `\botfigrule`: Same as `\topfigrule`, but put after the `\textfloatsep` skip separating text from the floats at bottom of page;
- `\intextsep`: Space left on top and bottom of an in-text float (default is `12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt`).

[image]

You can set any of these at the beginning of your document, and they will have a global effect from that moment onward, unless there is some command or environment explicitly resetting it.

To see what *your* settings for any of these parameters are, use `\the...`. For example, to see the value of `\floatsep`, use `\the\floatsep`.