# Page breaks after images in figures / minipages

Tags: spacing, floats

I'm using minipage environments for two images next to each other in a paper. My code looks like this:

```
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
                \center \includegraphics[width=7.8 cm]{./lorem.jpg}
                \caption{Lorem Ipsum}
            \end{minipage}\hfill
        \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
                \center \includegraphics[width=7.8 cm]{./ipsum.jpg}
                \caption{Ipsum Lorem}
            \end{minipage}      
    \end{figure}
```

When these images occur at the end of a page, however, and there's not enough room, they are moved to the following page. That's how it's supposed to be, of course; but when this happens, the space after the figure becomes too big. The space has the right size when the figure occurs somewhere in the middle of a page.

By inserting a `\clearpage` right before the figure manually, I can solve the problem. But as I'd have to do this everytime I change details of the layout, that's not really the best way.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space before and after in-text floats is determined by the `\intextsep` length (in standard classes, by default, `12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt`), while the space after top floats and before bottom floats is determined by `\textfloatsep` (by default, `20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt`). To achieve your desired layout, add the following to your preamble:

```
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
```

See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39809/510) answer for an overview of float layout parameters.

Comment: Using `\textfloatsep` and `\intextsep` definitely was the right idea. I'm still getting varying spaces underneath the figures though. I assume that this is due to the plus / minus, right?

Comment: @Daniel If you're using the `book` class and `\flushbottom`, quite possible.

Answer (score 2):

lockstep has provided the answer, this is more of a long comment (but should be useful nonetheless)

You can certainly use

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
...
```

but you have to be careful when putting two of them side-by-side, because the `minipage` environment inserts a little bit of horizontal space immediately after it- this gives an `overfull hbox` in your code.

You can prevent this by using a `%` immediately after it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=.85\textwidth]{./lorem.jpg}
                \caption{Lorem Ipsum}
            \end{minipage}% <-- NOTE this bit!
            \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=.85\textwidth]{./lorem.jpg}
                \caption{Ipsum Lorem}
            \end{minipage}      
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that you can specify the `width` of the graphic in terms of the `\textwidth` of the *minipage*, which is quite useful as it will scale nicely if you want to change the widths of the `minipage`s later on.

Comment: Certainly interesting, but where is the difference to the `\hfill` I used before?

Comment: @Daniel if you use two `minipage` environments, both of which have width `.5\textwidth`, then there is no space between them, so `\hfill` does nothing! Note in particular the `%` after the first `minipage`, it's important in this situation to prevent `overfull hboxes`

Comment: ah, alright! :)