# Placing table/figure inside paragraph

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap

In my thesis, I am struggling in placing the figures and tables. The options `[H]` or `[!htb`] are not in a position to rescue as for few sections in the thesis there are more figures and tables in comparison to amount of text in that section. Now as I need to place the figures and texts in the particular section only where they belong, there are lots of white space here and there in many of the pages. I tried the package `wrapfig` but there I get my figures wrapped on left or right side also. I want the wrapping in the top and bottom only, or in other words, to place the figures and tables inside a paragraph where no texts should be there on left and right side. I expect this to be easy as the problem is very common (I may be wrong). How can I achieve this?

The heights of both the tables and figures are half, 3/4th and full page A4.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the [placeins](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/placeins) package? On a separate note: It would be really helpful if you provided some informaton about the range of sizes of the floats. E.g., are they all quite small in terms of height and width? Are they generally of a size that four to six floats could fit on a floats-only page?

Comment: I believe this does not wrap text and my main concern is to remove the large white spaces in few pages. Without wrapping I think it is difficult to solve the problem as in few sections there are less texts and more fig/tables.

The heights of the figures are either full page or half page. The heights of the tables are half, 3/4th and full page.

Comment: I think the question here becomes *are they floats or aren't they?*  A proper figure or table should have a caption such that if it ends up a couple of pages from the corresponding bit of body text it will still make sense.  You may gain something by globally reducing your figure whitespace (have a look at (this answer)[http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39809/28808]).  You may also be able to tweak things by including the first figure earlier than you would like.  `placeins` does offer you a `\FloatBarrier` that might help, in combination with other ideas.